# Trying to parse a query string in a WPF Hyperlink but the NavigationService is null

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, query-string

I have this hyperlink:

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="Page2.xaml?dummy=Kirk">Go to page 2</Hyperlink>
```

And then this parsing code in the linked page `Page2.xaml.cs`:

```
public string GetQueryStringParameter(string key)
{
    var spl = NavigationService.Source.Query.Split(',');
    foreach (var s in spl)
    {
        var spl2 = s.Split('=');
        if (spl2[0] == key)
            return spl2[1];
    }
    throw new ArgumentException($"Could not find parameter {key} in query string {NavigationService.Source.Query}.");
}

public string Dummy => GetQueryStringParameter("dummy");
```

However `GetQueryStringParameter` crashes trying to retrieve the `NavigationService`, which is null for some reason. Why is the navigation service null? How else can I get the query string?

Answer (score 1):

I think your View/ViewModel is trying to access `Dummy` property while object is still not initialized, meaning someone is accessing `NavigationService` when it is not yet set by the framework. Make sure your code lets Page to initialize before accessing `NavigationService` property.

For example, if you are using `Dummy` property in view model, you can set viewmodel after your view is loaded:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Interesting... So how do I make my code wait for Page to be initialized?

Comment: Why can't you just skip it if `NavigationService` is null?

Comment: Oh, and then it will get bound later on when the `NavigationService` exists?

Comment: I tried that but the property just comes back as my default value of null that I set for when the `NavigationService` is null; it's never re-evaluated.

Comment: @ekolis Check my edits, if it does not help then I'll need more info about your scenario.